# Why does my build runs properly in local but not on my server?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I started deploying my application yesterday and I had a lot of issues. 
Parcel was running into a lot of errors, so I transfered my application to Webpack and I have as much errors as before.
Most of the errors are things like package that are not found when building on the server. 
For example, I get this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property `createHash` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/voloutjh/nodevenv/react/10/lib/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/index.js:25:5)
```

Is there any way I could be assured I won't run into this kind of error. I don't see why it builds properly on local, but not on my server.

N.B : The version of Node is higher on my server than on my local machine, so I guess it shouldn't be an issue ?

Comment: the issue could be node version. try to match node version both environment or try docker

Comment: If you upgrade your local machine's version of Node.js to be even with production, does the same problem occur? For that TypeError, it might be a webpack version error - try `npm/yarn cache clear -- forece && npm/yarn install` to update webpack to the latest version.